# What are the advantages of using multiple ports in a game?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

What are the advantages of using multiple ports in a game? I understand why some would use a combination TCP and UDP for different purposes, but why do some games use multiple TCP or UDP ports? Is there any advantage to this? I am asking because I find myself making networking code for my game and I wonder why others go out of there way to have multiple ports?

For example GTA V uses 5 UDP ports and Assasins Creed Revelations uses 4 TCP and 4 UDP ports.

Comment: Probsbly because the authors don't understand networking. Ports are a scarce resource. Don't waste them.

Comment: @EJP There must be some reason... GTA V for example uses
TCP Ports: 80, 443
UDP Ports: 6672, 61455, 61457, 61456, and 61458

Why 5 UDP ports? Many big games seem to be doing this?

Comment: 80 is HTTP. 443 is HTTPS. Using five UDP ports is criminal.

Comment: @EJP Maybe they have 5 different servers communicating with the single game?

Comment: That's not a reason to use five UDP ports.

Comment: @EJP Assasins Creed Revelations uses TCP:13000, 13005, 13200, 14001  UDP:3074, 7959, 14001, 21200... That is 4 TCP and 4 UDP ports... so this is 2 big games that use multiple ports. Why are they going over the port speed limit?

Comment: Their protocols probably do not support multiplexing multiple streams. In other words, poor design.

Comment: @o9000 I have read there is never a reason to use multiple ports, but seeing all these big games doing it makes me wonder there must be a practical reason to do it. Then again if it really is just bad design I guess the answer to this question is... "they did it because they were too lazy to do this... but always using 1 port is better".

Comment: Posting an answer since it does not fit here. But I am not addressing the exact question, since I have no clue about the inner workings of the specific games you mention.

Comment: "Ports are a scarce resource." That's not true. There is a limit of 2^16=64k open ports for *servers*; but he is talking about *clients* which do not have such limit. TCP clients multiplex by the (server address, server port, client address, client port) tuple which gives you a theoretical limit of 2^96 open connections.

Comment: @o9000 Certainly it's true. There are 64k-1 TCP ports and 64k-1 UDP ports per host, period. They are a scarce resource, and consuming seven of them in any one host can only be considered wasteful. These limits apply to both servers and clients. I was specifically referring to UDP ports, where the server/client distinction has little meaning. I was not discussing the number of open connections.

Comment: For UDP that is also incorrect, operating systems multiplex by the port number and the remote address, i.e. at 48 bits of state. But I won't debate this further.

Comment: @o9000 It isn't incorrect. There are only 64k-1 ports per protocol per host. Period. Use five of them and there are only 64k-6 left. You keep conflating ports with connections. You're not addressing the issue.

Comment: Since you can reuse them they are not a scarce resource. You have given no valid justification for your claim. And using strong language like "period" is not making you convincing.

Comment: @o9000 I repeat. You keep conflating ports with connections. What you've given us in fact is the reason why you only need one port. The 'valid justification' is that 65535-5=65530. If you open five UDP ports there are five less available  for other processes.

Comment: There is no such thing as "opening ports". Use technical terms please.

Answer (score 3):

There is always a reason.

Quite often they are not (entirely) technical. For instance one team is working on the inter-game chat functionality while another is working on the server-client protocol for game X. Then they are integrated into the same product, but nobody bothers unifying the protocols due to costs, time constraints, concerns regarding future maintainability etc.

There are also purely technical reasons:

If the game server and the chat server run on different locations, it is natural to use multiple connections; the alternative is to use a sort of reverse-NAT box on the server side, but it's risky since it's a bottleneck and a single point of failure.

Stability: if the chat server crashes or malfunctions you don't want it to also bring down the stream between the client and the game server, so it's safer to communicate on parallel connections.

Overall it's a classic example of theory meets practice: it would be great to use a single port (and connection), but it is more practical to separate the different transmissions and interactions for a variety of reasons.

A bit off topic, have you noticed how many connections are opened when accessing a web page nowadays? It's often several dozens. Would probably be an order of magnitude less without all the ads though. Anyways, compared to that, a game opening 5 connections is nothing.

Comment: Another reason is that multiplexing streams over a single TCP or UDP connection with *certain requirements* is a hard to solve problem. See QUIC and HTTP/2, it took a lot of effort from very smart people to solve this, and I am not sure even that is powerful enough for the low latency requirements of games.